# Obtaining matrix and column matches

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have some data from which I want to obtain some information. However, I ran into some problems for which I will be glad to get expert help.

Data and some information:

```
A = [1 0 -1 2 0 1;0 2 1 0 1 -2;1 1 0 2 1 1]%matrix
B = [1 3]#rows 1 and 3 are rows for searching.
struc.names = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'amber', 'grey','yellow']% a structure of column names.
required.names = {'blue', 'green', 'grey','yellow'}; % a structure of required column names
```

I tried to obtain 3 types of information as follows:

First: Get and save matrix for a subset of rows.

Second: I want to obtain a vector (populated with either 1 or 0) corresponding to columns of interest (required.names) compared to struc.names

Third: For rows 1 and 3, find matches between struc.names and required_rows when row elements are non-zero; also to have result output arranged according to the number of matches.

Problem 1:

```
 code for getting matrix:
 struc.names = {'blue', 'red', 'green', 'amber', 'grey','yellow'};
 required_rows = [1 3];
 for k = 1:length(required_rows);
    % open file for writing
    fid =fopen('ouput.txt','w');
    idx(k,:) = A(required_rows(k),:);
    fprintf(fid,'%d \n',idx);#print matrix
 end;
```

output obtained:

```
 1 0 -1 2 0 1 1 1 0 2 1 1
```

required output:

```
 1 0 -1 2 0 1 
 1 1 0 2 1 1
```

Problem 2: Obtain column vector for required.names = {'blue', 'green', 'grey','yellow'} when compared with struc.names;

I want to obtain 1(column name present) and 0(column name absent) in a vector like: [1 0 1 0 0 1]; I'm unsure how to write the code.

Problem3: Code for finding matches between struc.names and required_rows when row elements are non-zero and then obtaining sorted results arranged according to number of matches. Code:

```
struc.names = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'amber', 'grey','yellow']# a structure  of  column  names.
required.names = {'blue', 'green', 'grey','yellow'}; # a structure of required  column names
struc.names = {'blue', 'red', 'green', 'amber', 'grey','yellow'}
required_rows = [1 3];
% open file for writing, and Loop
fid=fopen('file.txt','w+');
for K = 1 : length(required_rows);
    idx = A(required_rows(K),:) ~= 0;
    if any(idx)
    struc.names = struc.names(idx)
    C = intersect(struc.names ,required_rows)       
    fprintf(fid, 'row A(%d,:) has the following matches:\n');
    fprintf(fid, '%s ', C{idx} );
    fprintf(fid, '\n');
    end
end
fclose(fid);
```

Sorted output (according to number of matches) required as:

```
 row 3: blue red amber grey yellow
 row 1: blue green amber yellow
```

Thank you

Comment: Maybe, you should cut that into three questions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem 1.

```
A(required_rows,:)

ans =

 1     0    -1     2     0     1
 1     1     0     2     1     1
```

Problem 2.
You can use intersect to find required.names in struct.names. intersect finds the common elements of two sets. Have a look at the [help](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html). The second parameter returns the indices of the intersection in struct.names. So in fact struct.names{match} are present in required.names.

```
v=zeros(1, numel(struct.names));
[~, match] = intersect(struct.names, required.names);
v(match)=1

v =

 1     0     1     0     1     1
```

Problem 3.

```
idx = A(required_rows,:) ~= 0;
[~,perm] = sort(sum(idx,2),'descend');
for i=1:length(perm)
    matches = struct.names(idx(perm(i), :));
    display(['Row ' num2str(required_rows(perm(i))) ' has the following matches: ' ...
    sprintf('"%s" ', matches{:})]);
end

Row 3 has the following matches: "blue" "red" "amber" "grey" "yellow" 
Row 1 has the following matches: "blue" "green" "amber" "yellow"
```

To get the percentage of matches in every row you need to divide the number of elements in matches over the number of elements in struct.names:

```
numel(matches)/numel(struct.names)*100
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help, angainor! The codes worked perfectly. Do you mind explaining these steps:'problem 2: [~, match] = intersect(struct.names, required.names);'

Comment: Many thanks for your help, angainor! The codes worked perfectly. Do you mind explaining these steps:`problem 2: [~, match] = intersect(struct.names, required.names);` `problem3:[~,perm] = sort(sum(idx,2),'descend');` and `sprintf('"%s" ', matches{:})]);`  If I want to find the percentage of matches in problem 3, will it be correct to code something like:(matches/struc.names)*100.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thanks once again for helping me out!